# Sub Class a Backbone.View Sub Class & retain events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a generic subclass of `Backbone.View` which has a `close` event listener.

```
var GenericView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events : {
        "click .close" : "close"
    },

    close : function () {
        console.log("closing view");
    }

});
```

I want to subclass this generic class and add some new events. However the below will overwrite the super classes (above) event object. E.g.

```
var ImplementedView = new GenericView({

    // setting this will stop 'close' in Super Class from triggering
    events : {
        "click .submit" : "submit"
    }

});
```

How should I create a sub class, in this case `ImplementedView` and retain the events?

I have found one way to achieve this, by extending the event object when the child class is constructed. However I need to re-trigger `this.delegateEvents()`, which I am guessing is not good. Can any one comment on this?

```
var ImplementedView = new GenericView({

    initialize : function (options) {

        _.extend(this.events, {
            "click .submit" : "submit"
        });

        // re-attach events
        this.delegateEvents();
    }

});
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't see you subclassing anywhere?? ImplementedView is just a variable referring to an instance of GenericView...

Comment: You either need to explicitly use `_.extend(...)` or have a similar functionality like the `.extend` method of the views...look through backbone.js to get a clue. But if I'm right it's because of the lack of explicit inheritance on the prototype chain. Calling `this.delegateEvents()` or `Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents.call(events)` seems to be the way to go

Comment: I will look through the docs. re your first comment: I am not calling the new operator, i though this was therefore subclassing via extending the Backbone.Model?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@Nupul is exactly right: you're not subclassing your `GenericView`.

In fact, subclassing isn't really the right word here, since JavaScript doesn't do classical inheritance.

So let's first try and understand what's happening here:

```
var GenericView = Backbone.View.extend( propertiesObj, classPropertiesObj )
```

`Backbone.View` is a constructor function, that when called with the `new` keyword, creates a new object for you.

Since this is JS, all function are really function objects, so `Backbone.View.extend` is just a function hanging off `Backbone.View` that does a few things:

1. It sets up the prototype chain, so you can access properties and call functions defined in the 'base' class
2. It creates and returns a new constructor function you can call (which here would be `GenericView`) to instantiate objects of your inheriting class
3. It copies itself to be a function hanging off the constructor function it returns so that you can further inherit.

So the correct way to set up the protoype chain you want is:

```
var ImplementedView = GenericView.extend({
  // implementation goes here
});
```

and NOT:

```
var ImplementedView = new GenericView({//stuff});
```

because this just creates a new instance of a GenericView.

Now, you still have a problem, because when you do something like:

```
var impl_view = new ImplementedView;

impl_view.events; // This isn't merged with the events you created
                  // for the GenericView
```

At this point there are different ways to get the result you want, here's one that uses `delegateEvents` kind of like how you did. Using it isn't bad, incidentally.

```
var GenericView = Backbone.View.extend({

  genericEvents: { 'click .close': 'close' },

  close: function() { console.log('closing view...'); }

});

var ImplView = GenericView.extend({

  events: { 'click .submit': 'submit' },

  initialize: function(options) {
    // done like this so that genericEvents don't overwrite any events
    // we've defined here (in case they share the same key)
    this.events = _.extend({}, this.genericEvents, this.events);
    this.delegateEvents()
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a nice answer.

Though the downside is having to paste: `this.events = _.extend(this.genericEvents, this.events);` in the init of every subview. But I suppose I can deal. Wish there was a more automatic way though.

Comment: The order of paramaters is backwards on this line  `this.events = _.extend(this.genericEvents, this.events); `

It should actually read - `this.events = _.extend(this.events, this.genericEvents);`. The first paramater is the destination, the second is the source.

Comment: @JoeLongstreet Notice the assign to this.events. As the comment explains, we don't want our subclass's events to be overridden. It should actually be `this.events = _.extend({}, this.genericEvents, this.events);`, as we don't really want to be altering the genericEvents object. I've edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 27):

Another option is to have a BaseView that overrides the implementation of Extend. Such as:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
        //base view functionality if needed
    });
BaseView.extend = function(child){
    var view = Backbone.View.extend.apply(this, arguments);
    view.prototype.events = _.extend({}, this.prototype.events, child.events);
    return view;
};
```

This will automatically extend all of your events for anything that inherits from the BaseView.

Comment: Nice solution that centralizes the behavior rather than distributes it like the other solutions.

Comment: Very nice. Is there a reason this is done by default in Backbone? Perhaps they didn't want to over-ride underscore's extend()?

Answer (score 10):

I like Mr. Shaver's solution, but for something less intrusive:

```
var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    events : _.extend({
        "change input": "handleInputChange"
    }, ParentView.prototype.events)
});
```

**Edit**: Yes, you have to do this in each child class, but it's useful when only a few children are needed, or when you don't control the parent "class".

Comment: But this has the same problem of having to copy and paste that code for every child view.

Comment: I like the use of `ParentView.prototype.events` rather than making a `genericEvents` on the parent. See my answer for how to do this without copy/pasting for each child view.

Comment: Agreed, your solution seems better ... although, now that I think about it, having having to worry about these kind of problems makes me feel uneasy about using OOP in JS overall

Comment: Wouldn't you want to reverse the order to this: _.extend( ParentView.prototype.events, { "change input": "handleInputChange"}), since the later values override prior values?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that's worked well for me. You can use the events object in both parent and subclass without extending in it each subclass. Just extend it once in the parent class:

```
APP.Views.GenericWizard = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click .btn-prev'   : function(){}
  },
  initialize: function() {
    _(this.events).extend(APP.Views.GenericWizard.prototype.events);
  }
});

APP.Views.RegisterWizard = APP.Views.GenericWizard.extend({
  events: {
    'blur #username' : function(){}
  },
});

var registerWizard = new APP.Views.RegisterWizard();
console.log(registerWizard.events);
// Object {blur #username: function, click .btn-prev: function}
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvote. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: I think Will Shaver is on the right track for the best solution. What would happen if I extended from RegisterWizard with additional events? The events from RegisterWizard would be lost. You have to consider the full prototype chain if you're going to attempt OOP in Javascript. There's really not a great way to do it, but again, Will's is probably the cleanest and most accurate way to do it.

Comment: @Chris, good point. My way does only support one level of subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful: http://kalimotxocoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/playing-with-backbonejs-views.html

Seconds what I mentioned about `_.extend(...)` and what you currently have...

Comment: I just want to say that the kalimotxocoding.blogspot.com posted above doesn't solve the issue and is particularly horrible. I don't recommend checking it out.

Comment: Don't look at the backbone hack. Look at the first way of doing it where you have to explicitly extend the events of the parent view in the child view.