# How should i structure class inheritance in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

I'm building intermediate classes for Backbone objects :

For instance, i have a `App.Router` that inherits from `Backbone.Router`, all my collections will inherit from `App.Router` instead of Backbone.

I'm not sure what the best-practice is / or if it will even work correctly.

One thing i'm not really sure is how to end the constructor, in Backbone's core lib, it does call directly the parent (in inherits), while i call the parent prototype with `__super__`.

I also extend a base Object to enable generic methods.

Does this seems OK ?

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    // Reference to views objects instanciated
    views: {},

    // Reference to collections objects instanciated
    collections: {},

    // Class constructor (can be overriden in subclass with the need of a parent call)
    constructor: function(options) {
        console.log(" \u2192App.Router::constructor()", [this, arguments]);
        var self = this;

        // Configure instance
        this._configure(options || {});

        // Extend App.Object
        _.extend(this, App.Object);

        // SO? : Is this the correct way to end constructor?
        return App.Router.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    // Class initialization (override in subclass without the need of a parent call)
    initialize: function(config) {
        d&&console.log(this.name + "::initialize()", [this, arguments]);
    },

    // Performs the initial configuration of a Router with a set of options.
    // Keys with special meaning are attached directly to the class
    _configure : function(options) {
      if (this.options) options = _.extend({}, this.options, options);
      var classOptions = ['registerKey', 'parent', 'collections', 'views'];
      for (var i = 0, l = classOptions.length; i < l; i++) {
        var attr = classOptions[i];
        if (options[attr]) this[attr] = options[attr];
      }
      this.options = options;
    },

    // Render a view with a collection & optional data
    render: function(className, options) {
    },

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968487/sub-class-a-backbone-view-sub-class-retain-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not change the constructor. You can do all this directly in the initialize method.

So:

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    this._configure(options)
    // no need to call super initialize as it is empty
  },
  _configure: function(){...}
});
_.extend(App.Router.prototype, App.Object);
```

That will be much cleaner IMO.